# Structural break near the end of training sample

Tags: time-series, vector-autoregression, change-point

I have multivariate time series (VAR), and i found a break near the end (84.7%).
I wanted to use a dummy variable in this situation, but even if I choose 90% training set, the dummy only trains on 100 values (i have 1900 values in total).Сould this skew the results?

Comment: Possible yes, although probably it will make bad forecasts because of lack of data, have you tried it?

Comment: @user2974951 Yes I tried, some of more flexible models are more or less fine, but usual VAR has only 2 significant coefficients out of 8 (I used 1 lag - its best by BIC).

Comment: OK, so you solved this then? It's not an issue?

Comment: @user2974951 I'm still looking for ways to fix VAR